# App will be locked if the app is kept in background for 2 min

Tags: ios7, xcode5, nstimer

i am trying to do like Users will be asked for an App Passcode while using the app for first time. 
App will be locked if the app is kept in background for 2 min.
User need to provide passcode to unlock the app like banking app.. i don't know how to implement this. As i am new to Ios.
please help me. Thnx in advnce.

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate.m file you'll find these boilerplate methods:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

You'll want to bring up the password dialog in either WillEnterForeground or DidBecomeActive. Read up on them to see which suits **your** specific needs.

I did something similar for a client a long time ago. We didn't like the visuals of the dialog appearing when the app became active so we actually brought up the dialog in DidEnterBackground. In our app it just looked better. But these are where you need to start.

Comment: i am using this code in - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application-                                                NSTimeInterval time = 0.5;
 self.locationUpdateTimer =
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(updateLocation)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
but the problem is timer is still working in forground. need help.